# Using RSpec to receive methods created on the fly for Ruby struct

Tags: ruby, struct, rspec

I would like to know how to use RSpec to stub a method created on the fly for a Ruby struct.

My code looks like this:

```
def test_method
  queue.poll do |message|
    puts message.body
  end
end
```

`message` is a Struct.  Method `:body` is of course not built into the Ruby struct class, but is created on the fly as part of an external library.  I'd like to know how to stub the call to `:body`.

My RSpec tests look like this:

```
let(:poller) { instance_double(ExternalLibrary::QueuePoller) }
let(:msg) { instance_double(Struct) }

before do
  allow(ExternalLibrary::QueuePoller).to receive(:new).and_return(poller)
  allow(poller).to receive(:poll).and_yield(msg)
end

it 'polls the queue' do
  allow(msg).to receive(:body)
  described_class.new.test_method
end
```

But I have the following error:

```
  1) polls the queue
     Failure/Error: allow(msg).to receive(:body)
       Struct does not implement: body
```

How can I run the tests properly?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a hash as a second argument to `instance_double`.  So instead of:

```
let(:msg) { instance_double(Struct) }
```

Use:

```
let(:msg) { instance_double(Struct, body: '') }
```

Not sure whether you will have top put Struct in quotes:

```
let(:msg) { instance_double("Struct", body: '') }
```

This is all based on this link: 
https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/verifying-doubles/dynamic-classes
which seems to solve the same kind of issue

Comment: I tried your approach with and without quotes around Struct, but neither works.